# Is there anything wrong with wrapping Data.Sequence in my own Queue type?

Tags: haskell

I want a queue for my application. From what I've read, [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) is the best option for production code. In order to keep my code elegant, idiomatic, and overall Haskelly, is there anything wrong with wrapping Data.Sequence up in my own Queue data type in order to hide the functionality I don't need?

Comment: One distinction you can make is that a `Sequence` is a data *structure*: it describes how things are laid out in memory (within some level of abstraction, anyway), but doesn't impose any meaning to the contents. A `Queue`, on the other hand, is a data *type*, which imposes meaning (e.g., if `insert(a)` precedes `insert(b)`, then `remove` will return `a` before it returns `b`), but without specifying how that is managed. Your data type can be implemented in terms of a `Sequence` or some other data structure.

Answer (score 10):

Nothing wrong at all - in fact, that's precisely what `newtype` is for!

Ideally, your types should reflect your intentions - whoever reads your code (including yourself, in the future, when you have forgotten what you did and why) should be able to tell what a type is *for*

So, even if your queue is merely a `Sequence`, wrapping it into your own `Queue` newtype will tell the (human) readers "this particular sequence is to be used for queuing" - besides the benefits of hiding non-required functionality, and preventing mixing up your values (i.e. no accidentally passing another `Sequence` that is *not* supposed to be a queue to a function that expects a queue).

Comment: In addition, if you ever want to change representations, this kind of wrapping makes it really easy, since you have already explicitly marked everywhere in the code that depends on the representation with the constructor